# Не пойму почему не работает спарсенный код?

Tags: php, парсер

Получаю содержимое тега head при помощи кода

```
`<?
$html = file_get_html('http://softobase.com/ru/');
foreach ($html->find("head") as $elements) {
    $head = $elements;
}
echo $head;
?>`
```

полученный при помощи этого код не отображает некоторые элементы, но если скопироваь вручную содержимое тега head с сайта который я парсю и вставить в мой сайт  то все работает. Почему так происходит? Я проверял, получаемый код при помощи парсера абсолютно идентичен исходному кода сайта который парсю.

Comment: покажите, что у вас выводит данный код.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/djamali/tp3zgdjj/

Comment: А что тогда вам еще нужно? это же вроде весь head

Comment: да , но тогда на сайте не работают некоторые функции, а если скопировать и вставить полученный head то все работает. ВОт что я не могу понять.

Answer (score 0):

Вы переопределяете переменную в цикле, а выводите ее только после цикла. Сделайте вывод в цикле:

```
<?
$html = file_get_html('http://softobase.com/ru/');
foreach ($html->find("head") as $elements) {
    $head = $elements;
    echo $head;
}
?>
```

Comment: тоже самое, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Замените штатную функцию  **file_get_html()** на пхпшную **file_get_contents()**:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://softobase.com/ru/');
$html = str_get_html($content);
foreach ($html->find('head') as $head) {}

echo $head;
```

По сути, для тега `head` и цикл не требуется *(как видите, вывод прописан за пределами цикла)*, поэтому можно просто массив преобразовать в строку с помощью *join()*:

```
echo join($html->find('head'));
```

Comment: @DjamaliMeslaurov результат, разумеется, надо смотреть в исходном коде.